# How to set image source in Panorama Control in Windows Phone 7 code behind?

Tags: image, windows-phone-7, panorama-control

I am trying to create a simple Panorama application, which is really similar to the default code when you choose to create a Panorama application in Visual Studio.

What I want is, I define my own `ItemViewModel` with an extra icon image field, so the new model has 4 properties: `Icon`, `LineOne`, `LineTwo` and `LineThree`. `Icon` is an image or an string of path of the image file, `LineOne`, `LineTwo` and `LineThree` are string type.

The default code has something like:

```
this.Items.Add(new ItemViewModel() { 
    LineOne = "runtime one", 
    LineTwo = "Maecenas praesent accumsan bibendum",
    LineThree = "Facilisi faucibus habitant inceptos interdum lobortis nascetur pharetra placerat pulvinar sagittis senectus sociosqu" 
});
```

In the `LoadData` method of `MainViewModel.cs` class, I am wondering if I can have something like that, but I can specify which icon image I want to set in this method? e.g.:

```
this.Items.Add(new NewItemViewModel() { Icon = new Image().Source == "/Images/lineone.jpg" , LineOne = "lineone", LineTwo = "linetwo", LineThree = "linethree" });
```

Thank you.

Comment: It is unclear what you are asking here. Please provide more code to give us more context.

Answer (score 0):

Make your `Icon` property as `string` and bind it to `Source` of `Image` control in xaml

```
 <Image ImageSource={Binding Icon} ... />
```

That you can setup your image like that (don't forget to set type of image as `Content`)

```
 this.Items.Add(new NewItemViewModel() { Icon = "/Images/lineone.jpg" , LineOne = "lineone", LineTwo = "linetwo", LineThree = "linethree" })
```

Comment: It's really strange, I can't find ImageSource under Image in the XAML. there is no such property called ImageSource, only Resources or Source. How to set type of image as Content? Is it in the XAML or code behind? Thank you

Comment: I found out the build action is in the property windows of the .xaml file, but if I change that from Page to Content, the InitializeComponent(); call inside MainPage method of MainPage.xaml.cs would complain doesn't exist. Did I do the right thing to change the build action at the .xaml file?

Comment: Yes, `Source`, not `ImageSource`. You can set build action of Images you want to display on property window (Not a `Page` build action)

Comment: Thank you, that works. To others, what I did was 1.set Icon as a string type, 2. <Image Source="{Binding Icon}" ... /> 3. right click the image file, select property, and set the Build Action from Resource to Content. Thanks Ku6opr